# Binomial Expansion related problem

Tags: combinatorics

If   ${}^n{C_0} - {}^n{C_1} + {}^n{C_2} - {}^n{C_3} + .. + {\left( { - 1} \right)^r}{}^n{C_r} = 28$. Then find the value of $n$.

My approach is as follow ${}^n{C_0} - {}^n{C_1} + {}^n{C_2} - {}^n{C_3} + .. + {\left( { - 1} \right)^r}{}^n{C_r} = 28 = {}^8{C_2} = {}^8{C_6}$

${\left( {1 - x} \right)^n} = {}^n{C_0} - {}^n{C_1}x + {}^n{C_2}{x^2} - {}^n{C_3}{x^3} + .. + {\left( { - 1} \right)^n}{}^n{C_n}.{x^n}$
Putting x=1

${}^n{C_0} - {}^n{C_1} + {}^n{C_2} - {}^n{C_3} + .. + {\left( { - 1} \right)^n}{}^n{C_n} = 0$

$ \Rightarrow 28 + {\left( { - 1} \right)^{r + 1}}{}^n{C_{r + 1}} + .. + {\left( { - 1} \right)^n}{}^n{C_n} = 0$

How do I approach from here

Comment: Show that $$\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom nk=(-1)^r\binom{n-1}r.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pascal's identity is sufficient :
$$ {N-1 \choose R-1} + {N-1 \choose R} = {N \choose R}$$

Since $${n \choose 0} = 1 = {n-1 \choose 0}$$

given expression is
$${n-1 \choose 0} - {n \choose 1} + {n \choose 2} - {n \choose 3} + \ldots + (-1)^r {n \choose r}$$

Operating on first two terms every step,

$$= \color{red}{- {n-1 \choose 1}} + {n \choose 2} - {n \choose 3} + \ldots + (-1)^r {n \choose r}$$

$$= \color{blue}{ n-1 \choose 2} - {n \choose 3} + \ldots + (-1)^r {n \choose r}$$

$$ \cdots $$

$$= \color{brown}{(-1)^r{n-1 \choose r}}$$

Thus as you have identified, $n-1 = 8$ and $r=2$ or $6$.